# If $\|x\|\leq \|y+z\|$ is $\|\alpha x\| \leq \|y+\alpha z\|$ for $\alpha\in[0,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vectors

If $\|x\|\leq \|y+z\|$  is $\|\alpha x\| \leq \|y+\alpha z\|$ for $\alpha\in[0,1]$?  For reference, this is not a homework problem, but it did come up in something I'm looking at.  If $\langle y,z\rangle\geq 0$, the proof seems pretty straightforward.  Simply
\begin{align*}
\|\alpha x\|^2 =& \alpha^2\|x\|^2\\
\leq&\alpha^2 \|y+z\|^2\\
=&\alpha^2 \|y\|^2 + 2 \alpha^2\langle y,z\rangle+\alpha^2\|z\|^2\\
\leq&\|y\|^2 + 2 \alpha^2\langle y,z\rangle+\alpha^2\|z\|^2\\
\leq&\|y\|^2 + 2 \alpha\langle y,z\rangle+\alpha^2\|z\|^2\\
=&\|y+\alpha z\|^2
\end{align*}
However, when $\langle y,z\rangle < 0$, I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha=0,1$, the solution is obvious.  Now lets consider $\alpha\in(0,1)$. However, for
\begin{align}
x=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0
\end{pmatrix},
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\-1
\end{pmatrix},
z=
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\2
\end{pmatrix},
\alpha=\frac 1 2
\end{align} 
we have
$$\|x\|=1\leq\sqrt 2=\|y+z\|$$
and 
$$\|y+\alpha z\|=0<\frac 1 2=\|\alpha x\|.$$
Thus, you're going to need some stronger conditions for your inequality to hold in general.  Perhaps some relation on the $x,y,z$?